# Difference Between CSS and XPATH

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

Difference Between CSS and XPATH ?

Which is the best locator in selecting Elements in selenium?

If Xpath is the better why? why should we use Xpath instead of CSS?

If CSS is the better why? why should we use CSS instead of Xpath ?

What are the advantages of both Xpath and CSS ?

What are the Disadvantages of both Xpath and CSS?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Neither. Use ID or name.

I **strongly** disagree with @Jon Duffy. If your CSS designers are up to snuff, they will create custom class names for the elements, so even if elements are moved around (XPATH changes), the class name itself stays the same. Even if CSS classes have different definitions, the name itself is the same.

Also, location by CSS is faster and more reliable. All Selenium "best practices" guides I've seen so far advised to prefer CSS over XPATH. See link [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8470/how-can-i-structure-selenium-tests-in-a-way-that-minimises-the-maintenance-work/8491#8491). In all Selenium best practices I've see so far, XPATH is **always** a last resort locator.

Of course, best locator is ID or name.

Even if **appearance or position** of element may change, it's ID or NAME should stay the same. So if you use them as locators, your tests are robust.

[CSS is faster and more reliable than XPATH](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/239/which-locator-do-you-use-with-selenium-css-or-xpath) at least on IE. Also, you want to run your test cross-browser, and IE will likely remain big part of target audience. So you need to talk to your developers and designers and explain them why for testing ID, names and CSS locators are preferable, so you can avoid the hassle of XPATH.

[Writing reliable locators](https://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2013/09/26/writing-reliable-locators-for-selenium-and-webdriver-tests/) - by Mozilla Web QA team

Comment: I Guess i didn't explain fully, We create custom tags for the testing and target them with XPATH. This means there are no long / flakey XPATH selections. This also helps maintain clarity between design code and test code. 
XPATH is defiantly more powerful as a selection tool. As of speed... I don't know, I would be grateful if you had a link regarding this.
We have gone through a complete front end redesign and the many of our tests were still functional afterwards as they were not tied to the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Css is liable to change; UI tweaks, making a site/app responsive etc.

By choosing to target elements XPATH the tags will likely stay around much longer and therefore requires less maintenance on your tests. If your site / app is generated using a framework you can have the XPATH targets generated in the back end and maintain some separation from the more changeable UI

Another point for generating XPATH in the back end. You may serve different CSS to different screen size, with XPATH these targets can remain the same across sites.

**Edit** We create customs tag that can be targeted with a simple XPATH expression, not good practice to have long complicated XPATH expression, this can only lead to flakey tests.

**Edit 2**

**XPATH:**

Pro's

- powerful selection of the DOM

Con's:

- no native support for xpath in IE (WebDriver uses a 3rd party library)

**CSS:**

Pro's

- looks simpler
- consistent support across browsers

Con's:

- Need to get designers on board
- Tests may need to be updated with UI changes

**Conclusion**

XPATH works for me as I have support of the developers, who will add custom tags for case where elements won't be unique (and therefore cannot select by ID) and I can add these tags to the code when needed. If out testers worked separately from the developers this would be a different story.