# Is knowledge in Webdriver needed in order to do automated cross-browser testing with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-ide, cross-browser-testing

I've been using the **Selenium IDE** to make automated tests but I can only run those tests within the IDE- which means I can only run them under Firefox.

Can I simply export my tests to one of the offered export languages and cross browser test from there or do I need to start using Webdriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting the tests may take care of ~90% of the task at hand.

The work you'll mostly likely need to do is patch ups, such as:

1. Calling upon the different webdrivers (*Chrome, Internet Explorer*)

   ```
     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); //as opposed to new FirefoxDriver();
   ```
2. Fixing brittle locators (*If your tests identify elements by `id`, they're stable. If they make use of `XPath` locators, your tests will be brittle because XPath isn't the same from one browser to another*)

   [Which locator do you use with Selenium: CSS or XPath?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/239/which-locator-do-you-use-with-selenium-css-or-xpath)

Starting off in the IDE with one language, the way you have, and then patching up to make things work across different browsers is a great way to move forward fast.

You don't need much knowledge of Selenium Webdriver. It will be self-explanatory when the test fails. And you have a lot of resources via Google to help you when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can export those tests and run them. Google is full with examples. Did you check it?

Then you simply use chrome or ie driver instead of firefox driver to run tests. (in that sense, yes, you need knowledge about webdriver to do cross-browser testing with Selenium)

And i imagine you will run into some problems on the way and it wont be simple and hassle free in the end.

So answer is Yes, but ..

And again, ask about details to google first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @8protons

- Just by changing the web driver you can execute your tests
- Instead of Firefox you can use Chrome or Safari

What I observed switching from FF to chrome:

- Few click doesn't work using .submit() or .click() or vice-versa
- Other elements like drop-down, text fields works well but in between you may need to fine tune it with your browser
- You analyze and implement those small things it would be faster to fix if you have a good knowledge about webdriver. Otherwise it will be fairly time consuming

Answer (score -1):

To write competent test (using pageobject design pattern) you need **real** programming skills. No IDE will generate for you test which will be easy to maintain and update as pages change (which they always do).

Tests are programs. There is no shortcut to become competent programmer. Maybe this one: Python is widely considered as best language for beginners. Yes, it will take you few years to become competent. There is no silver bullet. Deal with it.

Comment: lol thanks... I've been a programmer for several years so I don't have a problem with Webdriver or RC. But right now I'm on a time budget until I learn Webdriver and such; the IDE gets the job done for now. Your answer doesn't even remotely touch upon my question.

Comment: LOL. From the wording of your question I made assumption you are run of the mill IDE monkey, as we are getting daily. Maybe next time you need to describe your situation better so someone else might provide more focused answer. Have a nice day.